# Eclipse Checkstyle menu preference works in Eclipse Juno but not in Indigo or Helios

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno, checkstyle, eclipse-indigo, helios

I have installed my own Checkstyle update site plugin and it has installed well, but when I restart Eclipse and I check Checkstyle option in Window --> Preferences it appears the next error:

Unable to create the selected preference page.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle net.sf.eclipsecs.ui (854).

The error log is like this:

*org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle net.sf.eclipsecs.ui (854).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1207)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.getExecutableExtension(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$63.run(Workbench.java:2470)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator net.sf.eclipsecs.ui.CheckstyleUIPlugin for bundle net.sf.eclipsecs.ui is invalid
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/MApplicationElement
    at net.sf.eclipsecs.ui.CheckstyleUIPlugin.(CheckstyleUIPlugin.java:242)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:374)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:166)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.MApplicationElement
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 37 more*

That error occurs in Helios and Indigo, but not in Juno, and the plugin and feature version is the same.

What's my problem?? Help me please

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

That plugin explicitly depends on the Eclipse4 classes, which are only available in the 4.x stream of Eclipse. You can see it in the stack trace when the UI plugin of checkstyle is to be created:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/MApplicationElement at net.sf.eclipsecs.ui.CheckstyleUIPlugin.(CheckstyleUIPlugin.java:242)
```

If you really need the plugin for older versions of Eclipse, please use the Update manager of Eclipse to install it there, don't manually copy plugin jar files around. The update manager should be able to detect which version of the plugin matches your Eclipse version.

But my advice would be to use Eclipse Kepler, as that is currently the latest version with the most bugfixes.